# google cloud storage access through curl get signature error

Tags: macos, curl, terminal, google-cloud-storage

i am trying to access my google cloud storage through apis with curl. here is what i am doing in the reminal (osx) :

```
ACCESS_KEY="my key here"
SECRET_KEY="my secret here"
VERB=GET
CHECKSUM=""
CONTENT_TYPE=""
URI=""
DATE="$(date)"
stringtosign="$VERB\n$CHECKSUM\n$CONTENT_TYPE\n$DATE\n${URI}"
echo $stringtosign
AUTHORIZATION="GOOG1 $ACCESS_KEY:$(echo -ne "$stringtosign" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "$SECRET_KEY" -binary | openssl base64)"
echo $AUTHORIZATION

curl -X $VERB http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com$URI -i -v -H Content-Length:0 -H "Authorization:$AUTHORIZATION" -H "Date:$DATE"
```

and i am getting SignatureDoesNotMatch , The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.

the whole day i tried many other variations and i still get the same problem. i double checked the access keys and i dont know where else to look.

please help :(

Comment: The body of the response should include the expected stringtosign. What does echo $stringtosign display and what does the server say it expects? That should help you figure out the problem.